# Counting rows in data.table that meet a condition

Tags: r, count, data.table

I have the following table

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=rep(4:6, 3))
```

I want to count how many rows meet the condition (`y==3 & v==5`).

I can get the rows that meet the condition, so I could save them and then count the rows. However, I know it can be done more efficiently with `.N` , I just don't know how. My code:

```
require(data.table)
keycols = c("y","v")
setkeyv(DT,keycols) 

DT[J(3,5)] # This gets the subset I am interested in

DT[ , `:=` (count = .N), by = J(3,5)] # This is one of the multiple unsuccessful ways I have been trying to count the rows.
```

Anyone has any idea on how to make the last line work?

Comment: The new [Introduction to data.table](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html) and [Reference semantics](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) vignettes have more examples. Check [this page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944) for updates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about just

```
DT[.(3,5), .N]
# [1] 3

## These are also equivalent
## DT[J(3,5), .N]
## DT[list(3,5), .N]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

> DT[ y == 3 & v == 5, count := .N]